# Testing a frame based web application in Opera using Selenium 2

Tags: opera, selenium-webdriver

I am testing our frame based web application using Selenium 2. This is the simple code that tries to login a user, and on the resulting page switch to the frame with the content of the page:

```
driver.get("http://localhost/index.pl");
driver.findElement(By.name("session_username")).sendKeys("my_username");
driver.findElement(By.name("session_password")).sendKeys("my_password");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@value='log in']")).click();
driver.switchTo().frame("qabody_r_head");
```

This works correctly if I send in a `WebDriver` of type `FirefoxDriver`, `InternetExplorerDriver` or `HtmlUnitDriver`. But if the driver is of type `OperaDriver` I get an exception with the following error output.

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchFrameException: Invalid frame name qabody_r_head
Build info: version: '2.15.0', revision: '15105', time: '2011-12-08 09:57:28'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0_02'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
at com.opera.core.systems.scope.services.ums.EcmaScriptDebugger.changeRuntime(EcmaScriptDebugger.java:431)
at com.opera.core.systems.OperaDriver$OperaTargetLocator.frame(OperaDriver.java:772)
at SeleniumTest.testLogin(SeleniumTest.java:26)
at SeleniumTest.main(SeleniumTest.java:59)
```

Am I doing something wrong, or doesn't OperaDriver work with frames?

Answer (score 0):

Is this frame directly inside the top page, or inside a sub-frame? If it is the latter, you may have to start at the top of the hierarchy and select parent frame first.

I've noticed issues when using Dragonfly/test tools with frames but I thought they were resolved. If you could put a small demo somewhere I could have a look..

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same situation when using the OperaDriver.
I wanted to switch to a frame contained in the main window. I was not able to switch to the frame, and instead I got the following error
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchFrameException: Invalid frame name

Below are the steps I took when trying to select the frame:

```
//...
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@value='Save']")).click();
driver.switchTo().frame("SaveFrame");       
//...
```

Note that the above code works perfectly in IE, Firefox and Chrome.

I used Opera 11.60 when testing the above.
I wasted a couple of hours and did not find an answer to this one.
Has someone worked with the switchTo().frame() method for Opera and it worked ?